# Select specific grouped element

Tags: sql

Hi I would like to ask you because I cannot find solution.

For example I have data like that:

```
number | date            | user
10     |   2022-07-01    |   A
15     |   2022-07-08    |   A
9      |   2022-07-10    |   A
```

Right now I need get the number for user where date is the newer one.
In this case I need get value 9

Ofcourse I have many diffrent users it is only for illustrate the issue.
Now I would like to select all unique users with his number that date is the newer one.

Is it possible to do it in one query?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? In most you can solve this using a common table expression and generating a rank like this: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY DATE DESC)`. After that, select all rows where that rank equals 1

Comment: In Oracle there even exists an aggregate function for this (`KEEP LAST`).

Answer (score 2):

I like to teach these problems by breaking it down into smaller problems.

First, write a query that tells you which is the "newer one" for each user.

```
SELECT user, max(date) as newer_one
FROM tbl
GROUP BY user
```

Next, you can join that result back to the original data. My favorite style is called a CTE which makes things readable and easier to debug. Like so,

```
WITH newest AS (
SELECT user, max(date) as newer_one
FROM tbl
GROUP BY user
)
SELECT original.*
FROM tbl AS original
INNER JOIN newest
ON original.user = newest.user
AND original.date = newest.newer_one
```

Some RDBMS don't support this CTE style, but you can put the query in the body which makes it harder to read sometimes but will work basically anywhere.

```
SELECT original.*
FROM tbl AS original
INNER JOIN 
 (
   SELECT user, max(date) as newer_one
   FROM tbl
   GROUP BY user
 ) as newest 
ON original.user = newest.user
AND original.date = newest.newer_one
```

Comment: Josh Thank you. Great example.